# Centering an image that's nested in a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have it so that when on a mobile device, the image is above the text but both are centered and have equal margins on both sides. Is something like that possible given the following code? If so, how?

```
<p>
    <img src = "Images\Locations\paolo-warehouse-placeholder.jpg" alt = "Paolo's Hideout" style = "width: 390px; height: 240px;">
    (text)
</p>
```

Comment: Yes, it sounds doable. What seems to be the trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Give the paragraph element a style of `text-align: center;` and the image this style:

```
img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

This will center the image and the paragraph text and make sure the text is below the image.